# IONIC-KEYCLOAK No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: ionic-framework, oauth-2.0

When I try to recover the token like you said I have this problem.
can you help me?
Thank you

```
from origin 'http://10.112.10.199:8100' has been blocked by CORS policy: 
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

Comment: did you ever manage to resolve this?